# spring-multiple task execution with delay

Tags: java, spring

I have spring 3.0 app, which connects to WebService. The webservice requests are limited to 1 per second, and I need to fire ~1000 requests with 1 second delay between each.
I'm trying to do it using Spring TaskExecutor and I've found the example [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

But how can I set the 1 second delay between each taskExecutor.execute call?

The code from example I'm using:

```
    import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;

    public class TaskExecutorExample {

      private class MessagePrinterTask implements Runnable {

        private String message;

        public MessagePrinterTask(String message) {
          this.message = message;
        }

        public void run() {
          System.out.println(message);
        }

      }

      private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

      public TaskExecutorExample(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
      }

      public void printMessages() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
          taskExecutor.execute(new MessagePrinterTask("Message" + i));
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its called fixedDelay or fixedRate, depending on whant you need exactly

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="someObject" method="someMethod" fixed-delay="1000"/>
    <task:scheduled ref="someObject" method="someOtherMethod" fixed-rate="1000"/>
 </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

or

```
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay=1000)
```

or

```
  @Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
```

It is well documented in the Spring Reference, where you have taken the example from

Answer (score 0):

`TaskExecutor` is not the correct interface to use for this, it used for fire-and-forget "execute this whenever you can" operations. You should use `TaskScheduler` instead. This provides methods such as `scheduleAtFixedDelay` and `scheduleAtFixedRate`.

Check out the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) to read the descriptions of these methods - be careful, it's quite subtle.

Comment: @Ralph
but both methods fire the operation immediately(or after the delay), and then repeat it after delay/period. So in this simple example it will write: "Message0","Message1..." and then wait 1 second.
I want to write: "Message0", wait 1 second, and then write "Message1". Without repeating, and with delays between each operation.